# MAX() doesn't take into accound the WHERE filter

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT instrument_id, intervals.months AS months, MAX(timestamp) AS mints
FROM open_interest
INNER JOIN instruments AS i ON i.id = instrument_id
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT (((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE - p.month_interval) - interval '1441m'))::numeric * 1000))::bigint AS months
    FROM (
        VALUES(interval '0 month'),(interval '1 month'),(interval '2 month')
    ) AS p (month_interval)
) AS intervals
WHERE timestamp < intervals.months
AND i.kind = 'future' OR i.kind = 'perpetual'
AND i.expiration_timestamp > intervals.months
GROUP BY instrument_id, i.kind, intervals.months
```

On execution, I notice that I have multiple `mints` which are greater than `intervals.months`despite my filter on the `WHERE` clause. Here is the sample of the data:

```
instrument_id   months          mints
2               "1569887940000" "1569887929666"
7               "1564617540000" "1570029958614"
7               "1567295940000" "1570029958614"
7               "1569887940000" "1570029958614"
9               "1569887940000" "1569571200075"
1093            "1569887940000" "1569571200035"
1094            "1569887940000" "1569887929599"
1095            "1564617540000" "1570029958641"
```

Why does it happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your OR clause should have brackets since now it is ignoring the first condition:

```
SELECT instrument_id, intervals.months AS months, MAX(timestamp) AS mints
FROM open_interest
INNER JOIN instruments AS i ON i.id = instrument_id
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT (((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE - p.month_interval) - interval '1441m'))::numeric * 1000))::bigint AS months
    FROM (
        VALUES(interval '0 month'),(interval '1 month'),(interval '2 month')
    ) AS p (month_interval)
) AS intervals
WHERE timestamp < intervals.months
AND (i.kind = 'future' OR i.kind = 'perpetual')
AND i.expiration_timestamp > intervals.months
GROUP BY instrument_id, i.kind, intervals.months
```

Comment: Well this is embarassing.